# Rounding Bigdecimal values with 2 Decimal Places

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want a function to convert *Bigdecimal* `10.12 for 10.12345` and `10.13 for 10.12556`.
But no function is satisfying both conversion in same time.Please help to achieve this.

Below is what I tried.
With value 10.12345:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("10.12345");

a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP)
a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING)
a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN)
a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR)
a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

Output :

```
10.12345::10.13
10.12345::10.13
10.12345::10.12
10.12345::10.12
10.12345::10.12
10.12345::10.12
10.12345::10.12
```

With value 10.12556:

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("10.12556");

b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP)
b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING)
b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN)
b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR)
b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

Output :

```
10.12556::10.13
10.12556::10.13
10.12556::10.12
10.12556::10.12
10.12556::10.12
10.12556::10.12
10.12556::10.12
```

Comment: why are you rounding up for 10.12445?

Comment: if you have your own speical rounding rule, you have to implement on your own...

Comment: How is `10.12445` can be `10.13` ?

Comment: @Octopus Please check updated the second value

Comment: You seem to be testing "10.12445" in your second set of tests - didn't you want "10.12556"?

Comment: sorry for the typo,Thanks for reply just corrected. its  10.12556 only

Comment: @sunleo `10.12556` with `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN` gives `10.13`, and not `10.12`, and I think that this is what you want...

Comment: Yes That's correct.Thanks for enlighten me.Pls maks as Answer.

Comment: @sunleo I made an Answer.

Comment: Your question shows incorrect output: the last three lines of your second example give "10.13" when you print it. How do you print it? like this: `System.out.println(b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN));`? Maybe.. - do you realize that BigDecimal is immutable and that `setScale` returns a new BigDecimal, that it doesn't change the existing one?

Comment: Thanks for all the Answers and Replys.

Comment: Downvoted question as output shown does not match the code shown (where are the `println` statements?). And the output for `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` and for `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` in the second block is not what Java would return.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I think that the `RoundingMode` you are looking for is `ROUND_HALF_EVEN`. From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_EVEN):

> Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor. Behaves as for ROUND_HALF_UP if the digit to the left of the discarded fraction is odd; behaves as for ROUND_HALF_DOWN if it's even. Note that this is the rounding mode that minimizes cumulative error when applied repeatedly over a sequence of calculations.

Here is a quick test case:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("10.12345");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("10.12556");

a = a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
b = b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);

System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

Correctly prints:

```
10.12
10.13
```

UPDATE:

`setScale(int, int)` has not been recommended since Java 1.5, when enums were first introduced, and was finally deprecated in Java 9. You should now use `setScale(int, RoundingMode)` e.g:

`setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`

Comment: I prefer to setScale after the new BigDecimal in the same line, but this answer helps me. new BigDecimal("10.12345").setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)

Comment: `setScale(int, int)` has not been recommended since Java 1.5, when enums were first introduced, and was finally deprecated in Java 9. 
You should now use `setScale(int, RoundingMode)` 
e.g: `setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`

Answer (score 17):

Add `0.001` first to the number and then call `setScale(2, RoundingMode.ROUND_HALF_UP)`

Code example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("10.12445").add(new BigDecimal("0.001"));
    BigDecimal b = a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: a.add(new BigDecimal("0.001")).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP) tried this is not working ?

Comment: Not sure where the problem is for you. Try the code example I added, it prints "10.13". BTW you changed the question after I gave the answer, you originally asked to round "10.12345" to "10.12" and "10.12445" to "10.13".

Comment: Your problem is probably the same as why you are printing the wrong output in your question itself (`new BigDecimal("10.12556").setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)` is `10.13`, not `10.12`) as your printed. As I said above, the only thing I can think of is that you assume that `setScale` changes the BigDecimal - but it does not, as they are immutable - the method returns a new BigDecimal.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("10.12345");
    System.out.println(toPrecision(a, 2));
}

private static BigDecimal toPrecision(BigDecimal dec, int precision) {
    String plain = dec.movePointRight(precision).toPlainString();
    return new BigDecimal(plain.substring(0, plain.indexOf("."))).movePointLeft(precision);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
10.12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `setScale(newScale, roundingMode)` method three times with changing the newScale value from 4 to 3 to 2 like

First case

```
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("10.12345");

    a = a.setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); 
    System.out.println("" + a); //10.1235
    a = a.setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); 
    System.out.println("" + a); //10.124
    a = a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println("" + a); //10.12
```

Second case

```
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("10.12556");

    a = a.setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); 
    System.out.println("" + a); //10.1256
    a = a.setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); 
    System.out.println("" + a); //10.126
    a = a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println("" + a); //10.13
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, `setScale(int, int)`, has not been recommended since [Java 1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,%20int)), when enums were first introduced:

> The new `setScale(int, RoundingMode)` method should be used in preference to this legacy method.

It was finally deprecated in [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-int-).

You should call [`setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-) instead. It makes error checking much simpler, since you can't pass in an undefined `enum`, but you can certainly pass in an integer mode which is undefined.